# Thymeleaf .properties message

Tags: thymeleaf, message, application.properties

I recieve a stange output when I try to read message from .properties file using Thymeleaf. 
my html:

my .properties file:
message=Hello

my output:
??message_pl_PL??

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your container (e.g., Tomcat)?  If so, please post your HTML too.

Comment: Does your message properties file has the extension pl_PL? Based on this suffix the correct properties file is selected.